# How to properly download a Python module (xlwings) on mac terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.7, xlwings

I have been trying to install xlwings module (on python 3.7) from terminal and getting some errors. At the last try I have reached a point that when I type pip3 install xlwings I receive below error.

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=550 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/b_/kf3zc0xx3f51rbjcj5gcd9lh0000gn/T/pip-install-qo2pickz/psutil/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/b_/kf3zc0xx3f51rbjcj5gcd9lh0000gn/T/pip-record-vpk41akr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b_/kf3zc0xx3f51rbjcj5gcd9lh0000gn/T/pip-install-qo2pickz/psutil/

I don't know anything about terminal but open to learn. Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: alternatively, you can install git bash which gives you mac/linux style terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you need to download and install the xcode developer tools (you don't need the full xcode install). It should fix the problem. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381) on a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your suggestion. It actually worked and I managed to install xlwings. But now I get above error in my shell :/
Traceback (most recent call last):

 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings-0.15.2-py3.7.egg/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 10, in <module>
    import aem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aem'

Comment: do `pip install appscript` again. Best to do `pip uninstall appscript` first. Wheels are now available on pypi so installation should be not an issue anymore.

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately. I also tried with conda but still "no module named 'aem'". I have installed many modules without encountering an error on another device. The problem can be that I am using mojave, can't be?

Comment: @EvrimOzanYılmaz When you say you tried conda do you mean to install the full xlwings, or just aem. If just aem perhaps try install all of xlwings via conda: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/xlwings

Comment: I have installed all xlwings as in the website but still get the error no module named aem :/ I also downloaded xcode and still the same.

Comment: I have accomplished to work with xlwings after I downloaded whole xcode from appstore. Thanks